# Making a list of lists in R

Tags: r, pathway, gsea

I have a data frame columns are pathways and genes are rows

Like

```r
head(a[1:2,1:2])
  Release.of.Cancer.Cell.Antigens Cancer.Antigen.Presentation
1                          ARID1A                        ARG2
2                             ATM                        ATF3

str(a[1:2,1:2])
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Release.of.Cancer.Cell.Antigens: chr  "ARID1A" "ATM"
 $ Cancer.Antigen.Presentation    : chr  "ARG2" "ATF3"
```

I want to make a list of pathways containing their genes, something like

```r
str(h.sets)
List of 50
 $ HALLMARK_ADIPOGENESIS                     : chr [1:208] "ABCA1" "ABCB8" "ACAA2" "ACADL" ...
 $ HALLMARK_ALLOGRAFT_REJECTION              : chr [1:332] "AARS1" "ABCE1" "ABI1" "ACHE" ...
```

I done so

```r
h.names <- unique(colnames(a))
h.sets <- vector("list",length=length(h.names))
names(h.sets) <- h.names
```

But here I get error here

```r
for (i in names(h.sets)) {
    h.sets[[i]] <- pull(a[colnames(a)==i])
}

Error in `pull()`:
! Can't extract columns past the end.
ℹ Location 1 doesn't exist.
ℹ There are only 0 columns.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help please

Comment: Data frame is a type of list, so for most purposes you already have what you're asking. You can convert it into an ordinary list with `as.list(a)`. If that doesn't help, you should tell more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you using `pull`? Why not a simple `h.sets[[i]] <- a[i]`?